# File Sharing for highly confidential data

Tags: file-sharing, file-management

My company sometimes has to send large, highly confidential files to a specific customer (an individual person within an organization). We've been using a custom built (by me) solution, but we're looking for a replacement system as we've changed many things internally that make that solution less viable.

What I think we need is something along the lines of Dropbox, or filegenius-ftp but for highly confidential files. Dropbox doesn't seem secure enough for this.

The idea is that one of our employees would upload a file and then create a link to it for the customer. They would send that link to the customer via email. The customer would then click the link to get the file.

Clearly there are steps in here that are prone to security risks, so we'd need the link to be encrypted somehow, and for the customer to authenticate against the system to prove who they are. However, we want the system to be simple enough so that our employees don't have to spend hours setting up new users for each customer.

Any ideas of existing systems that can do this?

Kevin

Comment: Dropbox/Whatever with encfs?

Comment: Reading briefly about ENCFS it uses a system on encryption that would require our customers to setup and configure drop-box, rather than just clicking a link to download a file. Not friendly enough, by the looks of it. Sorry.

Comment: If you don't want to setup any software, there is no solution, except SSL for up and download.

Comment: `scp` may be an option, and if you had some programming up your sleeve, you could MinGW + OpenSSH + GTK + some logic :)

Answer (score 0):

Linoma Software just announced a new module in their GoAnywhere Services product that can do this, plus it stores your files onsite instead of in the cloud. It's called GoDrive. You can download a free trial at goanywhere.com (disclaimer, I work there) if you want to try it out.